# What are the main arguments the Catholic Church uses in support of the sole interpretive authority of the Magisterium?

Tags: catholicism, catholic-catechism, papal-magisterium

According to the Catechism ([CCC 100](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__PN.HTM))

> "The task of interpreting the Word of God authentically has been
> entrusted solely to the Magisterium of the Church, that is, to the
> Pope and to the bishops in communion with him."

What arguments does the Catholic Church use to support the idea that "the task of interpreting" has been entrusted **solely** to the Magisterium of the Pope and bishops in communion with him?

Answer (score 1):

According to the First Vatican Council, [*Pastor æternus* ch. 4](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/creeds2.v.ii.i.html#v.ii.i-p41.13) "Concerning the Infallible Teaching of the Roman Pontiff",

> **the supreme power of teaching** (*supremam quoque **magisterii*** potestatem*) **is** also **included in the Apostolic [primacy](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=35774)**, which the Roman Pontiff, as the successor of Peter, Prince of the Apostles, possesses over the whole Church, this Holy See has always held, the perpetual practice of the Church confirms, and œcumenical Councils also have declared, especially those in which the East with the West met in the union of faith and charity. For the Fathers of the Fourth Council of Constantinople, following in the footsteps of their predecessors, gave forth this solemn profession: "The first condition of salvation is to keep the rule of the true faith." And because the sentence of our Lord Jesus Christ can not be passed by, who said: "Thou art Peter, and upon this rock I will build my Church," [[Mt. 16:18](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=16&l=18-#x)] these things which have been said are approved by events, because in the Apostolic See the Catholic religion and her holy and well-known doctrine has always been kept undefiled.

*[*Magisterium*](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34698) (Church's teaching authority) < *magister* = teacher.